# Confused about drivers for my GPU

Tags: drivers, 17.10, dell, radeon, amdgpu

I recently bought Dell Vostro 15 3568 which has `ubuntuMATE 17.10`, according to [Dell official website](http://www.dell.com/in/business/p/vostro-15-3568-laptop/pd) my system has `AMD® R5 M415 with 2GB DDR3L vRAM` GPU ,but when i use `sudo lshw -C display` to know my GPU i get this

```
 `*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list        rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:280 memory:d1000000-d1ffffff memory:b0000000-  bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:281 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-    d003ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0040000-d005ffff`
```

According to this command i have `AMD Radeon HD 8550M/R5 M230` in system so am quite confused about my **GPU** and **drivers** for it.Help me in knowing **GPU** and also **drivers** for it.

Answer (score 0):

I’m fairly sure that is just the gpu processor model/graphics card model. they seem to be one thing.

Thanks for asking: Ben